# Convert camelCase string to dash-separated in Gradle (i.e. Groovy)

Tags: string, groovy, gradle

I have a bunch of string properties in a gradle build script, which is in `camelCase` (for example `"jmxConsoleWeb"`), and I'd like to split each into a `dash-separated` (e.g. `jmx-console-web`) string instead.

Is there a "non-hackish" way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved it like this:

```
public static String dashSeparated(String s) { 
     return s.replaceAll(/\B[A-Z]/) { '-' + it }.toLowerCase() 
}
```

Also take a look [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Utility-methods-for-camelcase-conversion-td4270219.html)

Comment: That's good enough for my purposes. I tried figuring out how to use the built-in (?) utility classes that the linked forum thread referred to, but I couldn't figure out exactly which one I needed so I just added this directly to my build script.

Comment: I don't know build-in way. If anybody knows tell us (=

Answer (score 8):

You can use Guava if you don't mind the extra dependancy.  Here's a Groovy script that demonstrates its use:

```
@Grab( 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1' )
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.*

String.metaClass.caseFormat = { from, to ->
  from.to( to, delegate )
}

assert 'varName'.caseFormat( LOWER_CAMEL, UPPER_UNDERSCORE )       == 'VAR_NAME'
assert 'var-name'.caseFormat( LOWER_HYPHEN, UPPER_CAMEL )          == 'VarName'
assert 'var_name'.caseFormat( LOWER_UNDERSCORE, LOWER_CAMEL )      == 'varName'
assert 'VAR_NAME'.caseFormat( UPPER_UNDERSCORE, LOWER_UNDERSCORE ) == 'var_name'
assert 'VarName'.caseFormat( UPPER_CAMEL, LOWER_HYPHEN )           == 'var-name'
```

Of course, in a Gradle script, you'd need to import guava into the buildScript dependencies if you want its methods available to the build itself

Comment: +1 Good Information Tim. Any reason why the former approach or alike has not been implemented in-built for Groovy String for camelCase yet?